# setting height with the height of children elements of it

Tags: html, css

it's **Style.css:**

```
.widget{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    height: auto;
}
.item{
    float: right;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

and it's **index.html:**

```
<div class="widget" id="reports">
                   <div class="item" id="km"></div>
                   <div class="item" id="km"></div>
                   <div class="item" id="km"></div>
                   <div class="item" id="km"></div>
</div>
```

but my problem is that in result "widget" have 0 height. what is the problem, I want to height of "widget" inherits from it's children.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: Instead of apply `float:right` to the `.item` apply `display: inline-block;` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/paVn5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your:

```
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
```

Add

```
               <div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Result will look like:

```
<div class="widget" id="reports">
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="item" id="km"></div>
               <div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Of course you can add the style for the clear class to your style sheet. You need to clear any floating divs befoure your parent div will recognize the height.